# I want to take screenshot of a specific region on webpage using pyscreenshot

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have used pyscreenshot package and I am getting below error while running my script. I am trying to take screen shot of specific region.
below is my script:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))

im.save('im.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

================================================================================
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
        prepare(preparation_data)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 509, in prepare
        '**parents_main**', file, path_name, etc
      File "C:\harsh\CodeForAutomation\latest_25jan2019\aha-gui-fvt\pytesseract\pytes\test_pyscreenshot_localised.py", line 9, in 
        im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyscreenshot__init__.py", line 67, in grab

```
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 46, in _grab

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyscreenshot\procutil.py", line 31, in run_in_childprocess
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** move your code inside `if __name__ == __main__` (which is a best practice anyway)

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 500, 500))
    im.save('im.png')
```

It seems like pyscreenshot  is using multiprocesses and forking.

Based on the error message you get and the examples on its [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/), every code using pyscreenshot  must be pickleable.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to run this script by making small change as below.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

if __name__ == '__main__':
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(100,100,800,800))
    im.show('im.jpg')
```